# NewtonSoft Json DeserializeObject empty Guid field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I'm using ASP.NET MVC C# with HTML CSS jQuery KnockoutJs frontend.

I have a modal contact form on my HTML page. The idea is that if I create a new contact the modal form pops up with blank values including a blank hidden id field.

If I edit a contact then the modal form pops up with filled out fields including that hidden id field.

In my controller I intend to do this:

```
public JsonResult Contact(string values)
{
    var contact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<contact>(values);

    if (contact.Id.Equals(Guid.Empty))
    {
         // create a new contact in the database
    } else
    {
        // update an existing one
    }
}
```

However, I get an error saying that `can't convert "" to type Guid`

How do you get around this with NewtonSoft Json, i've looked [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/Samples.htm) at the **Custom JsonConverter** and it seems to be along the right lines, however I'm not sure where to go with this.

Comment: Have you tried making the `contact.Id` property nullable? That might solve it.

Comment: I use the `Contact` model that is used in the database, so making it nullable would be bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A custom converter would look like this, but I feel like it's a bit overkill for something so trivial.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a <see cref="Guid"/> to and from its <see cref="System.String"/> representation.
/// </summary>
public class GuidConverter : JsonConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance can convert the specified object type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns <c>true</c> if this instance can convert the specified object type; otherwise <c>false</c>.</returns>
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Guid));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the JSON representation of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader">The <see cref="JsonReader"/> to read from.</param>
    /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
    /// <param name="existingValue">The existing value of object being read.</param>
    /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
    /// <returns>The object value.</returns>
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<Guid>(reader);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Guid.Empty;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the JSON representation of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="JsonWriter"/> to write to.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Contact
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(GuidConverter))]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
var contact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<contact>(values, new GuidConverter());
```

**EDIT**

I presume that your JSON looks a lot like this:

```
{
    "id": "",
    "etc": "..."
}
```

The problem would probably be fixed if you can do this instead:

```
{
    "id": null,
    "etc": "..."
}
```

Comment: Just testing it out now

Comment: Essentially, all it does is wrap the default converter in a `try-catch` block. If the conversion fails, it defaults to `Guid.Empty`. Not the most efficient solution. For example, you could use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` to avoid the exception in the first place.

Comment: The best solution would be not including the `Id` property in the JSON data at all. Can you do that?

Comment: where would you place that, are you talking about going through the string that is passed back to the action and find id and putting in a guid.empty into that?

Comment: I couldn't because I'm trying to achieve a single modal standard across the entire application, so in the front end only one place needs to be updated and the same in the back end

Comment: "IsAssignableFrom" hijacks dynamic. I had to keep doing equals.

Answer (score 3):

I faced issue that Guid.Empty (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) value was being deserialized as Null guide resulting in error. When I set the JsonSerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling value to DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate, on deserialization Guid property was being set to Default value

```
var serializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedString, new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate });
```

Comment: This answer just helped me to finish a 2 hour debug session. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fully example with GUID and JSON string

```
string content = "{\"data\":{\"Type\":\"Foo\",\"Description\":\"bar \",\"Software\":\"baz\",\"Version\":\"qux\",\"Url\":\"http://example.com\",\"DatabasePortNumber\":1,\"Id\":\"2cdc66f1-0000-0000-39ac-233c00000000\"}}";

var result_SystemText = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SystemApplicationResponse>(content);  //Will result in null-object
var result_Newtonsoft = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SystemApplicationResponse>(content); //Will result in correctly serialized object

    public class SystemApplicationResponse
    {
        public SystemApplicationDto Data { get; set; }
    }


    public class SystemApplicationDto
    {
        public SystemApplicationDtoType Type { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string Software { get; set; }

        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public int DatabasePortNumber { get; set; }
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    }

    public enum SystemApplicationDtoType
    {
        Foo = 0
    }
```

reference: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31465#