# How to serialize enum as string when the enum type is used in a generic class?

Tags: c#, json.net

In a custom class, I have a generic dictionary which has an enum type for the value type. Please note that the enum type is out of my control (part of a 3rd party assembly).

When I serialize such objet using Newtonsoft, enums are written as integer.

How to serialize enums as string?

I've tried using `StringEnumConverter` on the property but it applies only on the property itself, not when a generic is used. As the enum is declared in an external assembly, I can't apply StringEnumConverter directly on the enum.

Here is a repro sample:

**Output :**

> `{"ExtendedData":{"First":0,"Second":1}}`

**Code**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = new Data();

        data.ExtendedData.Add("First", Foo.Val1);
        data.ExtendedData.Add("Second", Foo.Val2);

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
    }

    public class Data{
        private readonly Dictionary<string, Foo> m_ExtendedData = new Dictionary<string, Foo>();

        public Dictionary<string, Foo> ExtendedData {get { return m_ExtendedData ; }}
    }

// !Actually from an external assembly
    public enum Foo{
        Val1,
        Val2
    }
}
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman, I disagree. Linked question in about changing the functionality for dictionaries, keys to be specific. This case only requires adding a `JsonConverter`, which is nearly not as drastic. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/c6JlZl

Comment: For your problem you can write custom JsonConverter. Good example you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908262/newtonsoft-json-deserializeobject-emtpy-guid-field

Comment: you can use:
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, new StringEnumConverter());

Comment: @PatrickHofman: you are right, this is a duplicate (wasn't able to find it). And I guess the accepted answer in the duplicate will solve my issue. Thx

Comment: One could argue if it is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-enum-as-string/2870420#2870420.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
var data = new Data();

data.ExtendedData.Add("First", Foo.Val1);
data.ExtendedData.Add("Second", Foo.Val2);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, new StringEnumConverter());
```